# Wall's presentation of the Steenrod algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, steenrod-algebra

In the paper "Generators and Relations for the Steenrod Algebra" (C. T. C. Wall, Annals of Mathematics, Second Series, Vol. 72, No. 3 (Nov., 1960), pp. 429-444) Wall shows that there is a presentation of the mod 2 Steenrod algebra $A$ with generators $s_i$ corresponding to $\mathrm{Sq}^{2^i}$ and relations of the form
$$ [s_i,s_j] = T_{ij}\quad 0\leqslant j\leqslant i-2$$
$$s_i^2 +s_is_{i-1}s_i+s_{i-1}^2s_i = T_i $$
where $T_{ij}$ and $T_i$ belong to the subalgebra generated by $s_0,\ldots,s_{i-1}$. Using this presentation Wall was able to solve a conjectured posed earlier by Toda.

**Question 1** Has anyone worked out the terms $T_{ij}$ and $T_i$ for low values of $i$ and $j$? I presume that the terms in $T_{ij}$ and $T_i$ are at least cubic in the $s_i$? Is this true? (I'll re-read the paper with a bit more care and probably figure this out, but perhaps someone can confirm this quickly).

Of course this gives presentations of the subalgebras $A(n)$ generated by $s_0,\ldots,s_n$ in $A$. It is easy to see, for example, that

- $A(0) = T(x\mid x^2)$
- $A(1) = T(x,y\mid \text{add } y^2 + xyx)$.
- $A(2) = T(x,y,z \mid \text{add } [x,z]+yxy, z^2+y[z,y])$

In the lovely *User's guide to spectral sequence* J. McCleary uses the first two presentations above to do some computations in the Adams spectral sequence: it turns out $A(0)$ admits a $(4,12)$ periodic resolution as an $A(1)$-module. A particular case of my question is:

**Question 2** Has anyone worked out a presentation of say, $A(3)$? Is it known if each $A(n)$ is finite dimensional? In this case, does one know how quickly $\dim A(n)$ grows like, for example?

I am definitely not well-versed in the story of this algebra, so if the question is answered by either a paper, or book, or if there is literature that points in the right direction, I am happy to keep reading that in lieu of a full answer.

Comment: Disclaimer: I presume that with some spare time I can compute the presentation of $A(2)$ suggested by Wall. My question is not "can this be done?" but rather "has this been done systematically enough for low values of $n$?"

Comment: Add: I added the presentation of $A(2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question 1: "Closed forms" for the relations are known, due to Grant Walker in what seems to be unpublished work. The relations are described in Wood's paper "[Problems in the Steenrod algebra](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/wood2.pdf)," (PDF) Theorem 4.18. For example,
$$
s_i^2 = s_{i-1} \chi(s_i) s_{i-1} + s_{i-1}^2 \chi(s_i),
$$
where $\chi$ is the antipode. I put "closed" in quotes because this reduces the problem to having a closed form for $\chi(s_i)$. Wood gives some information about that, too, and in any case, it's easy to compute for small values of $i$ either by hand or using SageMath.

Wood's paper is a nice place to find lots of information about the Steenrod algebra; I recommend it.

Question 2: Certainly each $A(n)$ is finite-dimensional: by Milnor's famous theorem about the dual of the Steenrod algebra, $A(n)$ is dual to a quotient of a polynomial ring, namely
$$
\mathbb{F}_2 [\xi_1, \xi_2, \xi_3, ...] / (\xi_1^{2^{n+1}}, \xi_2^{2^n}, ..., \xi_i^{2^{n+2-i}}, ..., \xi_{n+1}^2, \xi_n, \xi_{n+1}, ...).
$$
So its vector-space dimension is $2^\binom{n+2}{2}$.

Comment: Dear John: thank you, this is really useful. I think I almost opened that paper a few days ago!

Comment: I was just trying to access this link http://www.idealibrary.com/links/citation/0021%2d8693/188/203 in your website but for some weird reason it redirects to https://www.oladieta.com.br/. I thought you should know.